# Why these code is error: instruction operands must be the same size

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86

As I said:

These code:

```
mov     EBX, 0
mov     EBX, ofn.nFileOffset   
add     EAX, EBX                ;; error
```

get error: instruction operands must be the same size.

But when I edit:

```
mov     EBX, 0
mov     BX, ofn.nFileOffset   
add     EAX, EBX
```

It's ok.
I also test by Ollydbg to track the register but I don't see any different.

Anyone can explain

Comment: Add eax,ebx is not where the error is, but the line above it. ofn.nFileOffset is 2 bytes (word), that is why you can move it into bx, to move into ebx, change mov to movzx

Comment: Ah, it is MASM with its strange syntax... Don't use it. :)

Comment: `xor ebx, ebx` is equivalent to `mov ebx, 0` and saves three bytes. Use the first form when clearing a register.

Comment: @johnfound I don't see how strange syntax is involved with trying to do the illegal operation of moving something that's apparently 16 bits into a 32 bit register directly???

Comment: @Gunner: Thank you, but when I check in Ollydbg, I think if use MOV EBX, ofn.nFileOffset, it automatically expand zero bit to full EBX. And with MOVZX, it's also like that. What different ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ofn.nFileOffset   is 2 bytes.

and Mov instruction require equal size of 2 argument.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
xor     EBX, EBX
mov     BX, ofn.nFileOffset   
add     EAX, EBX
```

Now you will have `ofn.nFileOffset` value in `EBX`

Comment: Use `movzx ebx, ofn.nFileOffset` rather than emulating it with two instructions.  (You can use `movzx ebx, word ptr [ofn.nFileOffset]` to make the size explicit.)